# Mongoose $pull operator not removing ObjectID from array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

In my application, I have a post schema (shown below):

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    file: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    caption: {
        type: String,
        maxLength: 2000 
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    likeNum: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        min: 0
    },
    likes: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
    }]
})
```

I want to remove an `objectid` from the likes array when a user request is sent.

Route:

```
const post = await Post.findOne({_id: req.params.postid})
const user = req.user._id

post.update({}, {$pull: {likes: user}})
post.likeNum--
await post.save()
res.send('Unliked')
```

However the `objectid` is not removed from the array when the route is called. Can anyone spot why? Thanks.

UPDATE:

```
const user = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id)
```

UPDATE 2:

```
Post.updateOne({_id: req.params.postid}, { $pull: { likes: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id) } })
post.likeNum--
await post.save()
res.send('Unliked')
```

Comment: try converting _id to object id using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id)`

Comment: @turivishal Hello. This still has not removed the object id from the likes array. See update code above.

Comment: you are doing update operation on find object, just do separate query `await Post.update({}, { $pull: { likes: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id) } })`

Comment: @turivishal Hi this has still not worked. Please check updated code above

Comment: put `await` before query and no need to `post.save()` command because `updateOne` will save transaction, and if it still not work then try to convert your query `{_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.postid)}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do both operations in a single query no need to `findOne`,

- convert `req.user._id` to object id using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`
- `$inc` to decrees the counts of `likeNum`

```
await Post.updateOne(
  { _id:  req.params.postid },
  {
    $pull: { likes: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id) },
    $inc: { likeNum: -1 }
  }
);
res.send('Unliked');
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IiXZaRVKtRR)